# Filter data-frame rows based on conditions Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a data-frame `df` like this:

[`Date`: `mm/dd/yyyy`]

```
Date           Student_id    subject     Subject_Scores
11/30/2020     1000101       Math           70
11/25/2020     1000101       Physics        75
12/02/2020     1000101       Biology        60
11/25/2020     1000101       Chemistry      49
11/25/2020     1000101       English        80
12/02/2020     1000101       Sociology      50
11/25/2020     1000102       Physics        80
11/25/2020     1000102       Math           90
12/15/2020     1000102       Chemistry      63
12/15/2020     1000103       English        71
```

How can I get all the unique `Date`s for each of individual `Student_id`'s.

Output `date_df`:

```
Date           Student_id
11/30/2020     1000101
11/25/2020     1000101
12/02/2020     1000101
11/25/2020     1000102
12/15/2020     1000102
12/15/2020     1000103
```

**Also**, I need **counts** of unique `Date`s for each of `Student_id`:

```
Student_id   unique_date_count
1000101        3
1000102        2
1000103        1
```

Edits: I cannot drop any rows because of unique subejcts, so how can I get unique dates and its count for each of `Student_id`

Thanks for the help, in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df1 = df[['Date','Student_id']].drop_duplicates()
print (df1)
         Date  Student_id
0  11/30/2020     1000101
1  11/25/2020     1000101
2  12/02/2020     1000101
6  11/25/2020     1000102
8  12/15/2020     1000102
9  12/15/2020     1000103
```

And then [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = df1['Student_id'].value_counts()
print (s)
1000101    3
1000102    2
1000103    1
Name: Student_id, dtype: int64
```

Last if need `DataFrame` add [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) and [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df2 = s.rename_axis('Student_id').reset_index(name='unique_date_count')
print (df2)
   Student_id  unique_date_count
0     1000101                  3
1     1000102                  2
2     1000103                  1
```

Comment: Hi, Is that possible in any other way, other than `df.drop_duplicates()` ? As my extended dataset has other information (i.e unique `subject` for each `Student_id`), so I cannot drop duplicate rows.

Comment: @PNyak - Do you think `df[['Date','Student_id']].drop_duplicates()` ?

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to do:

```
df_new=df.drop_duplicates()
```

Second,you can do `value_counts`,

```
df_new['Student_id'].value_counts()
```